# Does a pipeline deploy automatically migrate the Heroku stack?

Tags: heroku

I have a set of older apps, which I moved to a new Heroku pipeline.

I successfully upgraded the Dev App to the new Heroku-16 Stack and deployed it to the production apps using the pipeline promotion.
The settings page of the production apps still says, that they use Cedar-14. Is this right? I assume, that they are also using the Heroku-16 stack?

I won't do any git commit again to the production apps, because I'm currently always deploying and releasing via pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered the question by myself...
Yes, the new stack also applies to targets of the pipeline.